# Spark condition on partition column from another table (Performance)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge parquet table partitioned on registration_ts column - named `stored`.

I'd like to filter this table based on data obtained from small table - `stream`

In sql world the query would look like:

```
spark.sql("select * from stored where exists (select 1 from stream where stream.registration_ts = stored.registration_ts)")
```

In Dataframe world:

```
stored.join(broadcast(stream), Seq("registration_ts"), "leftsemi")
```

This all works, but the performance is suffering, because the partition pruning is not applied. Spark full-scans stored table, which is too expensive.

**For example this runs 2 minutes:**

```
stream.count
res45: Long = 3
//takes 2 minutes
stored.join(broadcast(stream), Seq("registration_ts"), "leftsemi").collect
[Stage 181:>                                                      (0 + 1) / 373]
```

***This runs in 3 seconds:***

```
val stream = stream.where("registration_ts in (20190516204l, 20190515143l,20190510125l, 20190503151l)")
stream.count
res44: Long = 42
//takes 3 seconds
stored.join(broadcast(stream), Seq("registration_ts"), "leftsemi").collect
```

The reason is that in the 2-nd example the partition filter is propagated to joined `stream` table.

I'd like to achieve partition filtering on dynamic set of partitions.

The only solution I was able to come up with:

```
val partitions = stream.select('registration_ts).distinct.collect.map(_.getLong(0))
stored.where('registration_ts.isin(partitions:_*))
```

Which collects the partitions to driver and makes a 2-nd query. This works fine only for small number of partitions. When I've tried this solution with 500k distinct partitions, the delay was significant.

But there must be a better way ...

Comment: please share `desc formatted table` for both big and small tables.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share the table schema. Both tables have same schemas. The schema has 29 columns with various types (string, bigint, array, struct, timestamp, boolean). Both tables are partitioned on `registration_ts` column of type `Long`. I experience the same behaviour with various table schemas.

Comment: in your solution, instead of collecting `partitions` to the driver, sort and persist it. Then, you can iterate over it and collect smaller manageable chunks, perform small joins, and union the whole story. there are multiple implementations of this in production in my organization. There should be no performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that you can do it in PySpark and I've verified in Zeppelin that it is using the set of values to prune the partitions

# the collect_set function returns a distinct list of values and collect function returns a list of rows. Getting the [0] element in the list of rows gets you the first row and the [0] element in the row gets you the value from the first column which is the list of distinct values

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set
filter_list = spark.read.orc(HDFS_PATH)
    .agg(collect_set(COLUMN_WITH_FILTER_VALUES))
    .collect()[0][0]
```

# you can use the filter_list with the isin function to prune the partitions

```
df = spark.read.orc(HDFS_PATH)
    .filter(col(PARTITION_COLUMN)
    .isin(filter_list))
    .show(5)
```

# you may want to do some checks on your filter_list value to ensure that your first spark.read actually returned you a valid list of values before trying to do the next spark.read and prune your partitions